# SQL Query is only returning one result/row rather than all

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, inner-join

I have a complex sql query which is meant to return all the reviews given by a selected car however, I am only being shown one as seen below as opposed to all of them like in screenshot two.

[image: ScreenShot One]

[image: Should show all the cars from carID one, where you can see all the reviews]

This is my `DDL`:

```
CREATE TABLE carsType(
    carsTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    carsTypeName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(carsTypeID)
);

CREATE TABLE carCategoryType(
    carCategoryTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    carCategoryTypeName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(carCategoryTypeID)
);

CREATE TABLE cars(
    carID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    carsTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    carCategoryTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    carName VARCHAR(200),
    carArea VARCHAR(200),
    FOREIGN KEY(carsTypeID) REFERENCES carsType(carsTypeID),
    FOREIGN KEY(carCategoryTypeID) REFERENCES carCategoryType(carCategoryTypeID),
    PRIMARY KEY(carID)
);

CREATE TABLE carsReview(
    carID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    carMileage INTEGER NOT NULL,
    reviews VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(carID) REFERENCES cars(carID)
);

INSERT INTO carsType VALUES
(NULL, "Hatchback"),
(NULL, "Saloon"),
(NULL, "Sedan");

INSERT INTO carCategoryType VALUES
(NULL, "A"),
(NULL, "B"),
(NULL, "C");

INSERT INTO cars VALUES
(NULL, 1, 1, "Golf", "Germany"),
(NULL, 2, 2, "Ford", "USA"),
(NULL, 2, 2, "Pontiac", "USA");

INSERT INTO carsReview VALUES
(1, 10000, "Good clean car"),
(2, 3000, "Worth it"),
(3, 1000, "Brand spanking new"),
(1, 45000, "She is good"),
(1, 100000, "Gone son"),
(1, 23000, "Looking fine");
```

This is my complex `SQL` query:

```
SELECT tbl_cars.carID, tbl_cars.carName, tbl_cars.carArea, 
        (IFNULL(tbl_carsReview.averageMileage, 0.0)) AS finalaverageMileage , tbl_carsReview.reviews, tbl_carsType.carsTypeName, 
        tbl_carCategoryType.carCategoryTypeName
        FROM cars tbl_cars
        INNER JOIN carsType tbl_carsType ON
        tbl_cars.carsTypeID = tbl_carsType.carsTypeID 
        INNER JOIN carCategoryType tbl_carCategoryType ON
        tbl_cars.carCategoryTypeID = tbl_carCategoryType.carCategoryTypeID
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT carsReview.carID, ROUND(AVG(carsReview.reviews),1) AS averageMileage, carsReview.reviews
        FROM carsReview) tbl_carsReview
        ON tbl_cars.carID = tbl_carsReview.carID 
        WHERE tbl_cars.carID = 1
```

[image: Only returns one result rather than all the results from the <code>carsReview</code> matching <code>carID 1</code>]

This is my `sqlfiddle`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9a92c/8

Comment: Table aliases longer than the table names... I prefer the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `group by` in the subquery:

```
SELECT tbl_cars.carID, tbl_cars.carName, tbl_cars.carArea, 
       (IFNULL(tbl_carsReview.averageMileage, 0.0)) AS finalaverageMileage ,
       tbl_carsReview.reviews, tbl_carsType.carsTypeName, 
       tbl_carCategoryType.carCategoryTypeName
FROM cars tbl_cars INNER JOIN
     carsType tbl_carsType
     ON tbl_cars.carsTypeID = tbl_carsType.carsTypeID INNER JOIN
     carCategoryType tbl_carCategoryType
     ON tbl_cars.carCategoryTypeID = tbl_carCategoryType.carCategoryTypeID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT carsReview.carID, ROUND(AVG(carsReview.reviews),1) AS averageMileage, carsReview.reviews
      FROM carsReview
      GROUP BY carsReview.carID
------^
     ) tbl_carsReview
     ON tbl_cars.carID = tbl_carsReview.carID 
WHERE tbl_cars.carID = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want the reviews *and* the average, you need an additional `join`:

```
SELECT tbl_cars.carID, tbl_cars.carName, tbl_cars.carArea, 
       (IFNULL(tbl_carsReviewAvg.averageMileage, 0.0)) AS finalaverageMileage ,
       tbl_carsReview.reviews, tbl_carsType.carsTypeName, 
       tbl_carCategoryType.carCategoryTypeName
FROM cars tbl_cars INNER JOIN
     carsType tbl_carsType
     ON tbl_cars.carsTypeID = tbl_carsType.carsTypeID INNER JOIN
     carCategoryType tbl_carCategoryType
     ON tbl_cars.carCategoryTypeID = tbl_carCategoryType.carCategoryTypeID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT carsReview.carID, ROUND(AVG(carsReview.reviews),1) AS averageMileage, carsReview.reviews
      FROM carsReview
      GROUP BY carsReview.carID
     ) tbl_carsReviewAvg
     ON tbl_cars.carID = tbl_carsReviewAvg.carID LEFT JOIN
     carsReview tbl_carsReview
     ON tbl_cars.carID = tbl_carsReview.carID
WHERE tbl_cars.carID = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, but it only returns the first result. I want it to return ALL the results in the `carsReview` table that match the `carID = 1` so there should be four rows in the result query in the end, because I need to do something with those four comments

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci . . . Then you need two joins.  One to get the average review and one to get all the rows.  Alternatively, you might want to use `group_concat()` to combine information about the reviews into a single column.

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? I am not very good with SQL and I am finding this a bit challenging. Would mean a lot if you could help

Comment: Sorry sir, I am getting the following error after trying your latest `SQL` - `Unknown column 'tbl_carsReviewAvg.averageMileage' in 'field list'`

Comment: Thank you sir. Only problem is that the `finalaverageMileage` keeps on being `0` for every record. That is the only problem

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci . . . The calculation seems ok.